# Colors in adapter

Tags: java, android, colors, android-adapter

Sorry,my English not good.

I would my `TextView` paint in colors(from List),but I get the number like(-256,16776961 ......);

```
  GridView gvMain;

  ArrayAdapter adapter;
  ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     gvMain = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMain);
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        colors.add(Color.RED);
        colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
        colors.add(Color.GREEN);
        colors.add(Color.BLACK);
        colors.add(Color.BLUE);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(colors);

   TextView tvv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvv);
    tvv.setBackgroundColor(colors);//with that be  error!!!

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.item,R.id.tvv, colors);
    gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
    GridView();
   gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
  private void GridView() {
    gvMain.setNumColumns(5);
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "paint in colors"? The text color?

Comment: You need to do `colors.get(index)`...`colors` itself is a list. Does this even compile?

Comment: @KevinRobatel color all textView not  only text

Comment: @PPartisan but I have 50 TextView(5*10)

Comment: I'm referring to this line, `tvv.setBackgroundColor(colors);//with that be  error!!!`

`GridView();` is also suspect. Is this a method call?

Comment: @PPartisan Ohhh Yes it is metod,I added

Comment: So does this compile? Because there is no method `TextView#setBackgroundColor()` that accepts an `ArrayList` argument.

Comment: @PPartisan Yes that is all.

Comment: You have multiple TextView and want one color by TextView? Can you add your layout and maybe a drawing of what you want?

Comment: @KevinRobatel No I want color all(50)TextView.And I get 50 numbers like (-256,16776961 ......) that instead colors

Comment: The numbers are the colours...for instance, [`Color#GREEN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#GREEN) is just an `int` constant with a value of `0xff00ff00` (or `-16711936`)

Comment: @ PPartisan How I can fix that?